# Running an AppleScript script from within an AppleScript app

Tags: applescript

I'm implementing this code into an AppleScript app I made the other day, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to run another AppleScript script.

```
set filescript to (path to resource "file creator.scpt" in directory "Scripts")
run script (path of filescript)
```

The error said that It can't get a class PPTH of alias.

Comment: Delete `path of` and the parentheses. `filescript` is already an alias specifier

Comment: When I do that, it said resources not found.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your resource. My suggestion fixes the mentioned error.

Comment: May I suggest that you log the path after fixing it as suggested by @vadian, and verify that it's correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it currently:

```
run script alias (((path to home folder) as string) & "projects:Another Script.applescript")
```

So in this example, the other script that I want to run is in `~/projects/Another Script.applescript`. I use this to run another applescript within a script saved as text, or application.